# Weird permalink after install a new database Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, server, permalinks

I moved my old database from Yahoo servers to a new place. The new server already had a database, so what I did was integrate the old database into the new database. Originally in Yahoo, my website had the following permalink:

```
mysite.com/wordpress/services/web-design
```

For the Yahoo servers is mandatory to use an additional file if your domain, if your site will be developed in Wordpress (... mysite.com/wordpress/) you can put whatever name you want to that file but there should always be a file. As this is very bad for SEO, I moved my site to a new place. In the new server, my permalinks are:

```
mysite.com/services/web-design
```

Everything ok, however when I try to open the "graphic design" page the permalink is like this:

```
mysite.com/services/js-jquery-2/
```

First I tried to confirm that maybe there was a post or page created with that strange name. After checking everything was fine, there was no page or post with that name. Then I made a full search for the word "js-jquery-2" throughout the server (using the keyword search function from Dreamweaver) (I have the server as a backup on my computer.) No word was found in the entire server. Maybe is at the database, this strange word is maybe saved there but I do not know how to locate it, in any case finding this word is perhaps not the solution.

Other thing I notice is that there are two groups of tables inside the database with almost the same names, for example there is a "wp_options" and there is a "wp_vzea_options", they share almost the same, should I try do delete a group ? thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: The two groups of tables in the database look like there are two instances of WordPress on your server, which is weird in itself. Can you verify what names the tables have that you exported from Yahoo?

Secondly - WordPress shows what permalink a post or page will have in editing mode of that post or page, right below the title. Can you open the page in question in edit mode and verify that it has the correct permalink (I'm guessing web-desing) set up?

Thirdly, can you verify that the link scheme in WP configuration options is what you want it to be?

Comment: I'm unable to access the Yahoo servers however I have the database in my computer, the same that I uploaded it to my new server, maybe with some tool I can see their tables and compare, if that is what you are trying. Inside my dashboard if I go to "posts" and enter to one I'll see the permalink editing bar, but not editing capabilities to the services, I made a composition to explain better: [link](http://www.arsmodea.com/img/permalink_edit_ok.jpg) and [link](http://www.arsmodea.com/img/no_permalink_editing.jpg) and [link](http://www.arsmodea.com/img/permalink_menu.jpg)

Comment: Okay, that was indeed helpful. This 'Services' area that you show in the screenshots is not part of WordPress itself, it comes from a plugin. Do you know the name of the plugin which provides it? Alternatively, can you provide a screenshot of the Plugins page from WordPress?

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's a theme that I purchased called "Nictitate". You can see the plugin area in this link: link